# I need to code addEventListener inside a function and that function gets executed everytime a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, addeventlistener, function-call

**What is want:** There is a checkbox, whenever it is checked, an input box is added and whenever unchecked that input box gets deleted.

It is happening if i code it in a JavaScript not within a function.

If i keep it within a function and call that function as a onChange event in the html it behaves in a different way.

Javascipt:

```
var chkboxalbum=document.getElementById("chknewalbum");
    chkboxalbum.addEventListener("change",function(){
             "use strict";
        if(document.getElementById("albumpic"))
        {
            document.getElementById("albumpic").remove(); 
        }
        else
        {                           
            var input12 = document.createElement("input");
            input12.className='w3-input w3-border';
            input12.id='albumpic';
            input12.name='albumpic';
            input12.type='file';
            input12.style='width:70%; display:inline';
            var ptag=document.createElement("p");
            ptag.id='ptag';
            ptag.appendChild(input12);

            var anchorr=document.getElementById("songname");
            anchorr.parentNode.insertBefore(ptag,anchorr);      

            }           
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p><input class="w3-check" id="chknewalbum" name="chknewalbum" type="checkbox"><label class="w3-validate">New Album?</label></p>
```

I want to add a onchange attribute to the HTML and want to keep the above javascript in a function. How to do that ?

**EDIT1:**

I have tried to code the JavaScript within a fuction like i wanted to. Here is the code:

```
function addFiles()
{
  "use strict";
   console.log('Fired');
var chkboxalbum=document.getElementById("chknewalbum");
chkboxalbum.addEventListener("change",abc,true);    
}


function abc()
{

             "use strict";
             console.log('Event Fired');
        if(document.getElementById("albumpic"))
        {
            document.getElementById("albumpic").remove(); 
        }


        else
        {

            var input12 = document.createElement("input");

            input12.className='w3-input w3-border';
            input12.id='albumpic';
            input12.name='albumpic';
            input12.type='file';
            input12.style='width:70%; display:inline';
            var ptag=document.createElement("p");
            ptag.id='ptag';
            ptag.appendChild(input12);


            var anchorr=document.getElementById("songname");
            anchorr.parentNode.insertBefore(ptag,anchorr);      

        }}
```

**The Issue** in this code is the first time i check the checkbox the elements are not added but the check box is checked. From the 2nd change(by clicking the checkbox) it is happening like what i wanted , that is the html element is added and removed with the click.

What i am doing wrong ? Why the elements are not getting added with the first click?

Comment: Appears to be working for me? https://jsfiddle.net/92shjyhj/ You did get an error because there was no element in your example with the id of `songname` so i added it. Unless i misunderstand the issue?

Comment: who is calling addFiles()

Comment: @ste2425   You have called addFiles() within the JavaScript which is triggered onload. I want a fuction in the javascript which will be triggered onchange.

Comment: @user2181397 There is an html checkbox element whose onchange is calling addFiles()

Answer (score 0):

I saw error at this line.

```
input12.style='width:70%; display:inline';
```

This may be because not all browsers support assigning assigning a string which contains a textual representation of a CSS declaration block to the style property. So I have made the following change. Also the is no `div#songname` in the snippet posted by you.

So have to create an arbitrary dom element to make it work. Hope this will be useful.

```
var chkboxalbum=document.getElementById("chknewalbum");
    chkboxalbum.addEventListener("change",function(){
             "use strict";
       var alb = document.getElementById("albumpic");      
        if(document.getElementById("albumpic"))
        {
            document.getElementById("albumpic").remove(); 
        }
        else
        {                           
            var input12 = document.createElement("input");
            input12.className='w3-input w3-border';
            input12.id='albumpic';
            input12.name='albumpic';
            input12.type='file';
            input12.setAttribute('style','width:70%; display:inline'); // Changed here
            var ptag=document.createElement("p");
            ptag.id='ptag';
            ptag.appendChild(input12);

            var anchorr=document.getElementById("songname");
            anchorr.parentNode.insertBefore(ptag,anchorr);      

            }           
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0zhx0f4o/)

**EDIT 1**

```
addFiles()  // Call this function to attach event to checkbox

function addFiles(){
  "use strict";
   console.log('Fired');
var chkboxalbum=document.getElementById("chknewalbum");
chkboxalbum.addEventListener("change",abc,true);    
}


function abc()
{

             "use strict";
             console.log('Event Fired');
        if(document.getElementById("albumpic"))
        {
            document.getElementById("albumpic").remove(); 
        }


        else
        {

            var input12 = document.createElement("input");

            input12.className='w3-input w3-border';
            input12.id='albumpic';
            input12.name='albumpic';
            input12.type='file';
            input12.setAttribute('style','width:70%; display:inline');
            var ptag=document.createElement("p");
            ptag.id='ptag';
            ptag.appendChild(input12);


            var anchorr=document.getElementById("songname");
            anchorr.parentNode.insertBefore(ptag,anchorr);      

        }}
```

[jsfiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0zhx0f4o/3/)

Comment: Thanks but this did not solve the issue. Please go through my first edit.

Comment: @user61152 with same code and in the fiddle I can see checkbox is getting added

Comment: Yes it is working fine , but i did mention that i want to put those code in a function and call that function in the HTML onchange event in the attribute of checkbox element. 
Please go through my first edit.

Comment: Your update works but the function already gets executed before clicking the checkbox. So that is not actually a solution rather a trick.

Comment: @user61152 the function get executed because you want to add event listener in this way. According to your code the you have put addEventListener inside a function, which is not necessary also you can directly add a handler on the dom element or execute addEventListener from outside your abc function

Comment: I want addFiles() to get executed only when the checkbox is checked. and thus checkbox element's onchange event will call the method addFiles() and the elemnts will get addes and removed on clicking the checkbox according to the code written inside the addFiles().

Comment: @user218397 As u have commented in the code to attach event to the checkbox, if i dont attach the event as you have mentioned it still works. It did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
input12.style='width:70%; display:inline';
```

with

```
input12.style.width = '70%';
input12.style.display = 'inline';
```

Except for that it is working fine.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gohu8vmv/)

Comment: Thanks but this did not solve the issue. Please go through my first edit.

Comment: Same problem in your edit. You should not assign to `style`. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gohu8vmv/1/

Answer (score 0):

See here:

html:

```
<input id="cb" class="w3-check" id="chknewalbum" name="chknewalbum" type="checkbox">
```

Create new element

```
var cb = document.getElementById('cb');
cb.old_value = cb.checked;
```

Add onclick event

```
cb.onclick = function(){
    var new_value = this.checked;

    if(this.old_value != new_value){
        alert('checkbox changed');
        this.old_value = new_value;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rz1sehfh/

Comment: I want to know about the issue with addEventListener , What it is not working the first time i checked the check box?